# Objective C method declaration/ calling

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm doing a video tutorial on iPhone programming, it's a very simple calculator app. At one point I declare the following method::

```
- (NSString*)calculate:(NSString*)operation withNumber:(NSInteger)number 
{
    return nil; 
}
```

It's not implemented yet at this point. Then I want to call the method with:

```
self.display.text = [self calculate:[sender currentTitle] withNumber:[self.display.text intValue]];
```

Xcode is giving me an error here: 'expected expression'. 
What's wrong here? And what is `withNumber` in the method? I would understand

```
- (NSString*)calculate :(NSString*)operation :(NSInteger)number;
```

Thats a method that takes a string and an int as parameters and returns a String. I don't get what `withNumber` does here.

Comment: Where exactly is this expression expected? Xcode tells you the exact location including the position within the line.

Comment: In Objective-C every parameter following the first has an identifier. Objective-C is polymorph. `calculate:withNumber:` is different from `calculate:withInt:`. Both methods may exist at the same time. Unlike Java Objective-C does not use the number of parameters only (exceptions apply) or the sequence of their types to support polymorphism.

Comment: Frankly, I am wondering that you are working on some beginners tutorial without having the basics understood. If I were you, I would not take the risk of teaching something that I have completey misunderstood.

Comment: When you learn something new, do you read the manuals and documentation over and over without trying to do something yourself? If you do, thats an interesting but (to me) very whimsical approach. Thanks anyway for the clarification.

Comment: I think Hermann and me have both misunderstood each other. I'm not trying to make a tutorial myself, but I am following one.

Comment: All right. Yes, I did misunderstand that part ("I am doing ..."). However, I am not concerned about your way of lerning at all. I was just outlining the risk of teaching wrong stuff that you haven't understood yourself. Sorry about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, for it to work, you will need to remove the unnecessary spaces :

```
- (NSString*)calculate:(NSString*)operation withNumber:(NSInteger)number{
    ...
}
```

and on calling the method too of course.

As to 'what is withNumber ? ' : this is the way multi-input method look like in Objective-C, the name of the method does not precede the arguments. The method is actually named `calculate:withNumber:` in the runtime system

I strongly recommend reading [some beginner's guide](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/)

You could do `- (NSString*)calculate:(NSString*)operation :(NSInteger)number` and then you will have to call `[self calculate:myString :myNumber];` but the vast majority of Objective-C user would not do that : the language gives you the opportunity to clarify your code and specify what arguments is what : take that opportunity.

Comment: In addition to above answer here is a Apple's guide for beginners: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html

Comment: That takes time to get use to it, like everything else of course. But I find this quite handy and I believe it makes very clear and easy to read code. If you don't have any further inquiry, I recommend accepting this as an answer.